# How to compare means of categorical data on R

Tags: r

I am trying to compare means of categorical data, that is education (integer) grouped by sex (Male and Female). So I have used the following code to view their means:

```
gss %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(xbar = mean(educ))
```

This code provides a table:

```
Sex           xbar
Male          NA
Female        NA
```

I dont get why this is the case since my education (educ) vector has numerical values and NA (very few).
Please assist me get numerical values.

Comment: Add `na.rm = TRUE` in `mean` i.e `mean(educ, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dplyr approach.

```
library(dplyr)
gss %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(mean, sd))
```

Comment: @SfundoMabaso If the answer helped please consider selecting it as a solution!